# Opening a div and loading php content onclick, then allowing close on div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of javascript that is supposed to change the style of a div with display:none, then populate that div with content loaded from a php file.  My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="zone">
                    <div class="line">
                        <span class="capital_missing_3">W</span>ho shall yeve / to myne heed a
                            welle ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        Off bytter teers / my sorowes to compleyne ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        Of a grete condwyt / of trubly waters felle ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        Doun to stylle / fro myne eyen tweyne ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        To schewe the constreynt / of my dedly peyne ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        Whan I allas / behyld and dede see ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        My dere soone blede / in eu<span class="ex">er</span>y veyne ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line">
                        A twene too þeues / nayled to a Tree ؛ <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.QD.1')"><span class="compare">•</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="comparison" id="EETS.QD.1"></div>
```

And the javascript is supposed to open up the div at the bottom (id="EETS.QD.1") and populate it.  My first attempt still allows the toggle, but doesn't actually load any content:

```
function compare_toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = ((e.style.display != 'none') ? 'none': 'block');
   e.load('http:/www.minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/XQuery/test.php')
}
```

Since this didn't work, I thought I might need to invoke a separate function to load the page and tried that.

```
function compare_toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = ((e.style.display != 'none') ? 'none': 'block');
   function () {
       (this).load('http:/www.minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/XQuery/test.php');
   });
}
```

This not only doesn't display the content, but it breaks the toggle.  So I'm at a loss. I've looked at the similar questions here and all of them seem to suggest a solution similar to what I have as my second option. What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `document.getElementById()` returns the DOM object reference, but **[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** is a jQuery function. So the element on which we apply that function should be a jQuery object.

```
$(e).load('http:/www.minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/XQuery/test.php');
```

Alternative

```
$('#' + id).load('http:/www.minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/XQuery/test.php');
```

Comment: Thanks -- changing it to $(e).load solved my problem.  It works with small php files but not with the Saxon query php I'm running.  I suspect that's because it's loading the page into the div before the php is finished running, though, and that's outside the scope of this question.